# Qualcomm Atheros AR298X not working with recent kernels

Tags: kernel, wifi

My wifi doesnt work. It used to when the kernel was 3.18 or less. If I have a kernel more than 4.1 it will not work.

I would like to use ubuntu 16 and I don't want to downgrade the kernel.

**lspci | grep -i wireless** output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

**dmesg | grep ath** output:

```
[   15.115060] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x65
[   15.115064] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
[   15.115068] ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
[   15.115069] ath: Regpair used: 0x65
[   15.303548] ath9k 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
```

**modinfo ath9k** output:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     F7E3AF932B15681132EA595
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001043sd000085F2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000017AAsd00004026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000017AAsd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E099bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E091bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E081bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E08Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E07Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd0000A120bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A4bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002813bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002810bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Fsd00007202bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002F82bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000218Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000218Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002182bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002130bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000813bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000803bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000692bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00001832bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000832bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000612bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000652bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000412Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd00004129bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000144Dsd0000411Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001028sd0000020Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd00002005bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd0000217Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000103Csd000018E3bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000213Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000682bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd000006A2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000662bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000672bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000622bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E069bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd0000302Bbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003026bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003025bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002F8Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd0000218Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A3bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd000028A1bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002812bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001B9Asd00002811bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00006671bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00001842bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000842bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd000006B2bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv000011ADsd00000632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000185Fsd0000A119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000105Bsd0000E068bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv00001A3Bsd00002176bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000036sv0000168Csd00003028bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000037sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv00001A56sd00002003bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000010CFsd00001783bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000064bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000014CDsd00000063bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000103Csd00001864bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006641bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006631bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001043sd0000850Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002110bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001969sd00000091bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000017AAsd00003214bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv0000168Csd00003117bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv000011ADsd00006661bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000034sv00001A3Bsd00002116bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000033sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001043sd0000850Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C01bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00001C00bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F95bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001195bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001F86bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001186bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001B9Asd00002000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Fsd00007197bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E04Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006628bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000011ADsd00006627bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001C56sd00004001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002100bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002C97bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003219bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv000017AAsd00003218bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C708bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C680bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000C706bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Ebc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd0000410Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004106bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000144Dsd00004105bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003122bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000168Csd00003119bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000105Bsd0000E075bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002152bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd0000126Abc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002126bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00001237bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv00001A3Bsd00002086bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv00001A56sd00002001bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv00001A56sd00002000bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv00001A3Bsd00002C37bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd00001536bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000010CFsd0000147Cbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000185Fsd0000309Dbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A32sd00000306bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006642bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv000011ADsd00006632bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000105Bsd0000E01Fbc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A3Bsd00001C71bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000029sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000027sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000024sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000023sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          platform:qca956x_wmac
alias:          platform:qca953x_wmac
alias:          platform:qca955x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar934x_wmac
alias:          platform:ar933x_wmac
alias:          platform:ath9k
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)
```

Comment: Could you please post the contents of `dmesg | grep ath` ? This seems lightly related to a ath10k firmware bug. - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1520343

Comment: Done. I edited the topic with the output

Comment: Well, this seems to be more related with Country Code issues(`EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map`). I would suggest you to test by removing this module and passing the country code as parameter the module load with modprobe but, it ALSO seems that this driver have the country code STATIC on its sources - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137234 .Lemme think a little more...

Comment: What about if you remove this module and try to load without the hardware encryption acceleration and disable powersave features? - `modprobe -r ath9k` and then `modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1 ps_enable=0`

Comment: I tried those commands and now I cant even find a network.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. But no. I couldn't get it working. The only way was to downgrade the kernel.

Comment: This card on my 2010 27" iMac has been slow for some time but recently in the 5.4 kernel it's gone to complete shit. 1-4Mbps when I have 100Mbps download and I'm less than 3 meters, LOS to the residential router... Does anyone have a solution???